# No Such Module Xcode Obc-j to Swift in Single File

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I realize this is a common bug, but I have tried many other solutions, and believe I have a new wrinkle to it so I'll ask here.

I have this class in which I am trying to

```
import FBSDKLoginKit
```

But I get a no such module error. **However**, this class used to be in Objective-C, **and** I am able to do the same import in other (Swift) classes, but not this one.

Here is my podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Community' do
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.30'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.30'
  pod 'GoogleMaps', '~> 2.5'
  pod 'GooglePlaces', '~> 2.5'
  pod 'CropViewController'
  pod 'ImageSlideshow', '~> 1.5'
  pod 'GBHFacebookImagePicker', '~> 2.0'
  pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'
  pod 'TwilioChatClient', '~> 2.0.1'
#  pod 'TwilioAccessManager', '~> 0.1.1'
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7'
end
```

What gives?

Comment: Is it possible you are trying to import from a different target? The podfile says that only files in target (module) `Community` can import the SDK.

Comment: Good thought, but under target membership, Community is checked off.

Comment: actually, when I unclick CommunitySDK it works..?

Comment: That's probably because the class won't be even compiled :)